# Is there a LaTeX editor supporting Subversion out of the box?

Tags: editors, revision-control, ide

Actually I am new to Subversion. Shortly speaking, Subversion is a tool to manage versioning of documents, especially for software developers. You can find the details [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Subversion).

I have a team to write a book using LaTeX, each member can create, update and delete the supporting files. To avoid any loss of data, I want to manage the synchronization using Subversion.

Is there a LaTeX editor supporting Subversion out of the box?

EDIT 1: Thanks all for your response. 
I just wait for a couple of days to get more options from others. Then I will mark as the answer, of course not so objective :D

Comment: Also consider http://git-scm.com/.

Answer (score 21):

Use the same editor you are using today, and use subversion with [tortoise svn](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/). Tortoise is a simple and good windows explorer extension.

Comment: I agree wit Johan. I use subversion for software development and I think this is the best solution, you can keep using the editor that best suites your needs and have the benefits of svn at the same time. You may be losing some good features of an editor that doesn't have built-in svn, it's not worthy.

Answer (score 12):

I wish I could say TeXShop, my editor of choice, but I can't.  There's always [emacs](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SubVersion) and [Eclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/).

Comment: Eclipse is available on Windows, is it not?

Comment: Emacs is also available on Windows.

Comment: Thank you @Matthew Leingang and @Mikael Vejdemo-Johansson for the response. I will figure out those to find one suits my need.

Answer (score 11):

Auctex on Emacs:

1. [SubVersion, Emacs Wiki page](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SubVersion);
2. [Auctex, same place](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AUCTeX).

The other editor, Vim, has [a Subversion plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=922).  Vim does have special support for editing Latex &c, but it's not such a polished offering.

Both Emacs and Vim work well on Windows.  Take a look at the [GNU FAQ for Emacs on Windows](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/windows/faq.html).

Comment: At the danger of starting two simultaneous flamewars: emacs also has a nice git plugin: magit. http://philjackson.github.com/magit/

Comment: And a nice Git plugin for Vim is [fugitive](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive).

Answer (score 11):

[TeXstudio](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/) is a LaTeX IDE that has built in support for Subversion. I've not used it with Subversion myself, preferring Mercurial, so cannot vouch for how good its support is.

[image: SVN Options]

[image: File - SVN]

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the usual suspects (vim, emacs, etc.), for editors actually designed for LaTeX in particular, I believe [jLaTeXEditor](http://jlatexeditor.endrullis.de/) does. I don't use it personally, however.

Answer (score 3):

I use WinEdt on my Windows XP. There's a component for SVN which you can easily add:

http://www.winedt.org/Config/menus/svn.php

It works fine with Tortoise SVN (for Windows).

Answer (score 3):

Eclipse + [Texlipse](http://texlipse.sourceforge.net/manual/installation.html) + Subversive is the best option in my opinion. You need to download and unpack eclipse first. Then you can simply install the texlipse and subversive plugins. If you are familiar with eclipse, texlipse is surely the best tex editor for you. If not, it will surely be useful since eclipse does have a plugin for every file format under the sun. Furthermore, it is multiplatform and it has a built-in compare capability. 
By the way, eclipse keeps a local history for every file being edited automatically. So, if you are the only person who is working on the tex project, you may not need to install subversion at all. See [here](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-55.htm).

Answer (score 2):

BBEdit of course!
Sometimes I need to edit TeX files in BBEdit rather TeXShop. Then I use a script that calls TeXShop for typesetting and previewing PDF files.
There is a Subversion Menu in BBEdit.

Answer (score 2):

The two plugins available for Eclipse's SVN support [are sub-par at best, and dangerous at worst](http://journals.jevon.org/users/jevon-phd/entry/19739). I personally prefer using TortoiseSVN and my favourite LaTeX editor.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Geany](http://www.geany.org). It's not really a LaTeX editor but rather a simple yet powerfull text editor / IDE that is not as overwhelming and huge as Eclipse might be. It has plugins for [LaTeX](http://frank.uvena.de/en/Geany/geanylatex/) and [version control](http://plugins.geany.org/geanyvc.html) that includes SVN.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote myself a small bash script using the [inotify-tools](http://inotify-tools.sourceforge.net/) (see [this unix.SE question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5515/863)), which does the following things every time I save a file (you can also have it watch an entire directory/tree):

- `git commit -am"autocommit"` (you'd replace this by `svn`, though you should really consider git instead...)
- `latex` (or `pdflatex`)
- view the compiled document, or trigger the opened viewer to reload the file if needed
- if compilation failed, `git commit --amend -m"autocommit, not compiling"` (alternatively, you could only commit on successful compilation)

Now I can track down to the minute when I did change what in my Diplom thesis... (And the repository is still very small despite my including all used images)

Comment: [Here](https://www.sharelatex.com/blog/2012/10/16/collaborating-with-latex-and-git.html)'s a nice post about git+latex

Comment: This is *wrong*, IMO. You do not want to create a commit every time  singleyou save.

Comment: @Jubobs it's better than no commits at all though. I currently have TeXnicCenter set up to commit on each compile, but amend if the last commit failed, which is slightly better than my original suggestion. of course you can still use `git rebase` later on to merge commits into more significant hunks. But honestly, with very few exceptions I never used my repo for anything but a simple rewind, for which the auto-commit works just fine

Answer (score 1):

You could consider an ownCloud installation - it supports file versioning and can be mounted through WebDAV as a drive. If you have some cheap hosting, it is quite easy to work with, and a lot of people do.
I have used it for this kind of thing.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: I don't think owncloud's WebDAV support includes the extensions needed for Subversion clients to work.  [Keeping versioned backups](http://doc.owncloud.org/server/5.0/user_manual/files/versioncontrol.html) is not enough - if it can't merge simultaneous edits, it's n't a viable alternative to subversion.