# Is there a \newcommand manager program?

Tags: macros, editors, gedit

I type my latex document with gedit.
I use a lot of macro to facilitates typesettings.
I put all of them just after the `begin{document}` tag.
For a homework question says, I use at least 20 macros.
For example, in a question involving sequence

```
\newcommand{\xn}{x_n}
\newcommand{\yn}{y_n}
\newcommand{\xns}{\left\{ \xn \right\}}
\newcommand{\yns}{\left\{ \yn \right\}}
```

The problem is I never remember which one I created before.
Also, it's distracting, when writing a sentence, to always go back to the top of the document to create the macro I need.
It breaks my thinking follows.

I was wondering, what people do to facilitate that.
In an Eclipse IDE world, when writting code, I can use a function without defining it, then ask Eclipse to generate the body of the function.
Is there some kind of program which helps to manage `\newcommand`?

The answer doesn't have to be limited to gedit.

I know I can externalize macros in a `command.tex` file say.
I do this for general purpose macros, like probability notation, parenthesing,...
It is really macros specific to a question which are hard to manage.
It's not practical to define a general set of macro `command_homework.tex`.
The macros must be created on a question by question basis.
For example, in a question on sequence `\xn` is `x_n`, while for a question on limit it is `\frac{x}{n}`.

Comment: I use TeXMaker, in which you can add arbitrary macros to the auto-completion feature. I wonder if there is any editor that does that automatically.

Comment: @marczellm texstudio does so. It shows every command defined by ``\newcommand`` (I would guess in the actual document or project) in its autocompletion menu automatically.

Comment: But isn't it conterproductive having so many new defined commands that you cannot remember which you defined and how? Above that it will make the code quite unreadable especially if you define the same completely different depending on context...

Comment: Maybe this is not your real question, but I think it worthwhile to expend a few extra keystrokes and keep your code readable.  In fact you save *no* keystrokes using `\xn` instead of `x_n`, and for that you gain ambiguity.  Use a keystroke text expander like AutoHotKey or TextExpander to generate template code and fill-in the parameters.  Save macros for cases of major semantic or presentation markup.

Comment: @BenediktBauer I understand your point, I was afraid of this side effect, when I begin using this method. But, after using it for while, I found my latex code is expressive. Somehow, the exact definition of the command doesn't matter. When I write on sequence I know what I mean by `\xn`, so if I want to talk about convergence of `\xn - \zn`, the meaning guide me in the `\newcommand` maze. As for clarity, define `\axnzn` as `\left| x_n - z_n \right|`. Then, a phrase like "If `\axnzn` is small then `\axnyn` is small" (note the `yn`), is really clear.

Comment: I would find such a plethora of rather nondescriptive commands confusing:  if not now, in several months from now when I try to reread the document.  Nevertheless, if you have experience with Eclipse (as you seem to suggest), I believe you should be able to configure it to work with your LaTeX code in the manner you describe.  Unfortunately, I primarily use emacs as my editor and my experience with Eclipse is not sufficient to provide an answer beyond this comment. [see here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16035/22413)

Comment: A generic way of treating this situation would be to create a separate file that contains all your macro definition. Call it `macros.tex`. Then, just *before* `\begin{document}` (since it's good practice to separate content from structure), add `\input{macros.tex}`. Then you can switch between these files to see what you defined and how. The add bonus is that this now is transferable to other documents as well.

Comment: @NicolasEssis-Breton You seem to contradict yourself: if you know what `\xn` means, then you don't have to look for it in the preamble. If you find yourself not remembering whether you have defined a shortcut or not, then you're probably overusing these shortcuts. To me `\axnzn` is by far less clear than `\lvert x_{n} - z_{n}\rvert`

Comment: @egreg Yes, it looks like a contracdiction. I mean I know what `\axnzn` means, but I always forget if I already defined or not `\aynzn`. Also, checking this is tedious. I guess clarity is a subjective matter. Still, our discussion effortlessly use `\aznyn` without ambiguity.

Comment: As @MatthewLeingang said, macros are best used for *semantic markup*, such as `\newcommand{\set}[1]{\left\{#1\right\}}`. This helps another reader (or yourself at a later time) to understand the code faster. Shortcuts like `\aznyn` may give you a small speedup when writing, however they decrease readability, and as you described, even you keep forgetting which ones you have yet to define, so overall it's not very effective. Your point may be valid though, if you have to write the same formulas like 6-8 times and the document is not for long-term preservation or collaborative work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may not be the answer you're looking for, which is why I made it first as a comment.

I think it worthwhile to expend a few extra keystrokes and keep your code readable. In fact you save *no* keystrokes typing `\xn` instead of `x_n`, and for that you gain ambiguity that comes from having to remember how (or whether) you defined the macro.

Use a keystroke text expander like AutoHotKey (Windows) or TextExpander (Mac) to generate template code and fill-in the parameters.  Some IDEs (like TeXShop, and vi/emacs) have key combinations to do this too.  Save macros for cases of major semantic or presentation markup.

Comment: With time, your initial comment sank in me, and I now reserved macro for case of *major semantic*. Thank you, and also the other members, for teaching me the right path.